# css parent container no scroll bars

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a jquery scrolling image display similar to a lot of others that are out there but I'm really struggling to get past one road block.
I basically want to create a parent container around this bit of code so that the browser window doesn't scroll. Sometime of a viewport I guess? I've tried a million different things. My css just isn't good enough

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/68unq/

Thanks!

Comment: you would have to change your holder's width to something less than 400px with position relative while the images has to be positioned absolute, out of the container to create the viewport effect.

Comment: anyway, you would have to update your jquery accordingly with that change

Answer (score 1):

Why have you got arbitrary styles in the middle of your HTML? Anyway, take them out of the HTML, put them in the CSS, and add an ID to your container.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68unq/2/

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="holder" >
        <img src="http://placehold.it/290x27" class='img'>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/257x65" class='img'>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/270x27" class='img'>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/257x120" class='img'>
    </div>
<div>​
```

css:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: I see.. I must have accidentally copied them when I created the fiddle. The tags were not started nor closed correctly but had no affect on function. Your answer gets me a little bit closer but it has removed the image resize funtionality. Is there a way to set the height of #container to resize without javascript/jquery? When I set it to auto everyone disappears.

Comment: meant to add fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/68unq/7/
compare browser resize functionality on the newest link to my original:
http://jsfiddle.net/68unq/

Comment: scratch that. Compare to this update of the original: http://jsfiddle.net/68unq/8/
Thanks!